# VAR and Granger causality test

Tags: r, time-series, vector-autoregression

Is it necessary to calculate VAR before Granger causality test so that we can have the lag length to be used in Granger causality test

Answer (score 1):

Granger Causality can be defined as:
"X is said to Granger-cause Y if Y can be better predicted using the histories of both X and Y than it can by using the history of Y alone." [1](http://davegiles.blogspot.hk/2011/04/testing-for-granger-causality.html)

or in other words:
"A time series X is said to Granger-cause Y if it can be shown, usually through a series of t-tests and F-tests on lagged values of X (and with lagged values of Y also included), that those X values provide statistically significant information about future values of Y."
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granger_causality)

This is essentially what a vector autoregression model does.

Also wikipedia says: "Multivariate Granger causality analysis is usually performed by fitting a vector autoregressive model (VAR) to the time series."

Granger causality is therefore more a form of structurally summarizing VAR models.

For some more information: [here](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Granger_causality)

Answer (score 1):

No need.From varGranger causality test  unidirectional  or bidirectional causality can be found out which fullfills the purpose of causality test.